# MVC Field Level Security

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-5

What's the best way to allow different levels of access to UI fields based on a user's role?

On some screens we may want to have a field read-only for one role, hidden for another and editable by yet another role. A lot of the answers to similar questions have suggested having different ViewModels (and views?) per role that containing only the properties you want users in that role to edit, but that involves a lot of duplication -we'd have 3 or 4 very similar VMs, with only a few properties / Bind attributes different between them. We'd then have to handle the mapping of these different viewmodels back to the model in the Controller.

It also means if a user wants to change the permissions for a role we need to make a code change.

In contrast to this, in one of our web forms projects we have full field level security with all rules stored in the database and applied at runtime, so changing a role's permissions on a control does not require any code changes.

How we could implement this with MVC?

If configuration-only field level security isn't possible with MVC, what's the best way to implement field level security for different roles? Do we really need n copies of each ViewModel and View?

Edit to add we've found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/875547/Custom-Roles-Based-Access-Control-RBAC-in-ASP-NET?display=Print) which stores permissions for roles in the database, but the application permissions are still defined in code. This calls a controller method in the View:
`if (ViewContext.Controller.HasPermission("ViewRestrictedHRData"))`), but so far looks the best solution I've seen

Just to add we are after something more configurable at runtime, both in terms of which roles have which permissions and adding security to any field on the page without having to add any code around each field in the View.

Comment: Hi @Matt, did you find any solution? How do you even save this permissions in your DB?

Comment: The permissions in the database is described in here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/875547/Custom-Roles-Based-Access-Control-RBAC-in-ASP-NET?display=Print

Comment: I ended up using ActionFilters to alter the model before it gets to the view and then change it again on the way back before it gets to the controller, using security rules defined in the database.

So you could define in the database for View Models of type Person, hide the FirstName property for users in Role X.

Answer (score 1):

You can use razor syntax to check if the user is in a particular role.

```
@if(User.IsInRole("Administrator")) {
    Html.TextBoxFor(...);
}
```

Comment: This is just hard coding the Admin role permissions in the View, we were after something more configurable at runtime, both in terms of which roles have which permissions and adding security to any field on the page without having to add any code around each field